# Name for the intentional reduction in quality in a non-software, price discrimination setting

Tags: definition, price-discrimination

Is there a general term in economics for the intentional reduction in quality to reduce deviation to the worst alternative in price discrimination? Like "crippleware," but applicable in non-software settings?

Answer (score 2):

"Lemonization" [I guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Market_for_Lemons). I didn't [exactly](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-34266-0_4) make up that term with that meaning, but I suspect you won't see it often.

Comment: I had not seen lemonize as a verb before. I think in my setting the goal is not to make the market unravel, but maybe this is as close as I can get without coining my own jargon.